# Problem in integrating the FitzHugh-Nagumo model

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

I am using the FitzHugh-Nagumo model to perform some simulations concerning neuronal networks dynamics.
The model equations are:

$\frac{dv}{dt}=a_3^3v^3+a_2v^2+a_1v+bw+I\\ \frac{dw}{dt}=1/\tau(v-w)$

When I try to numerically integrate these equations, for several set of parameters ($a_1,a_2,a_3,b,I$) and initial data $(v_0,w_0)$, the method does not converge to any solution. In particular, I am using ode45 (and ode15s) in Matlab. The message is:

> Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size
>   below the smallest value allowed (3.552714e-15) at time t

Do you have any idea about what could be the problem? It would be solved? Do this means that the solution does not exist?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What range of parameters are you considering? If $a_3>0$ the $v$ component of the solution might blow-up in finite time.

Comment: I have different set of parameters that describe different networks. The case I am studying right now involves $a_3<0$, but at a certain time I  increase the external input $I$ by adding to $I$ a current step. Since $a_3<0$, do you think that is the new $I$ the leads the solution to blow up? Moreover, I have just plotted the nullclines in the case of $a_3>0$. I obtained three stationary solutions with one stable. Why are you sure that the solutions will blow up? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean by "method does not converge to any solution" ? Could you attach plots that you've obtained? Can you point where exactly (at which point of phase plane) ode45/ode15s struggles to integrate?

Comment: If $v(0)$ is large enough and $a_3>0$, $v$ will grow and _might_ bow-up. Compare with the equation $y'=y^3-y^2$; $y=1$ is a stationary solution, but if $y(0)>1$, the solution blows-up. Another possibility for things going wrong is that at some time $t$ $v(t)=w(t)$, producing a singularity in the second equation,

Comment: I may have read the equation incorrectly. Is the second equation $(1/\tau)(v-w)$ or $1/(\tau(v-w))$?

Comment: Even if the integration doesn't finish, you will still see some results. If you look at the results you should find which term is blowing up and where, which might give you something to think about.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre It's $\frac{v-w}{\tau}$. This system is slightly different from typical FitzHugh-Nagumo form (IMO), but vector field definitely should be defined on the whole phase plane :)

Comment: Hard to help more without seeing your actual code (including all parameters so it's runable). Make sure that you check your implementation to look for sign errors or other bugs. Also check that the units of your parameters are consistent.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your kind answers, and sorry for my late. Actually, your answers were fundamental in making me aware about the stiffness of FHN and the fact that there are several parameters sets that make it hard to be integrated. Thanks again!